# How to SSH into windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, ssh, debian

I have a debian based linux distro (Crunchbang) running on an old laptop (really old).
I want to ssh into windows xp (on my pc) from my debian laptop and run windows programs in GUI from my laptop.
Is that possible ? How to achieve this if it is possible at all ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to connect via SSH you need to install a ssh daemon for windows just like you would run one on linux. [Here is a list of ssh daemons](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows) from a server fault question.

However if you want to interact with the desktop that will likely not be possible with SSH. You could do this with linux to linux via X Windows forwarding but Microsoft does not have that kind of system. You will need to use a cross platform desktop sharing software like [Team Viewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) or [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) to connect and "share"<sup>1</sup> the desktop space. Or if you want "log in"<sup>2</sup> to the laptop just use [RDP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)<sup>3</sup>  to connect.

If you are only using SSH to provide security or access through your router both VNC and RDP can be tunneled inside a SSH session. I don't know if Team Viewer can, but it uses their own server to act as a randevu point so it can get through NATed firewalls without port forwarding.

---

<sup>1: You share the same desktop space on both screens, moving the mouse on one will move the mouse on the other.</sup>
<sup>2: You won't be able to see what is happening on screen on the laptop.</sup>
<sup>3: Most Linux distros support RDP out of the box, however it looks like crunchbang does not. You can install [Remmina-XFCE or rdesktop](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=8331) which adds support to do it. They are both in the package manager.</sup>

Comment: Note that incoming connects via RDP are not supported on Windows XP Home edition. Otherwise I'd say it's the best one could get. But *please,* @Ashlie, don't expose RDP as is to the Internet if this is what you intend to do as XP is almost EOL'ed and will stop receiving security updates soon.  On a LAN isn't supposedly OK to set up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [OpenSSH for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshwindows/), but I am not sure if you can open something on screen of remote computer.

Problem is that Windows (as well as Linux) have more virtual screens, which is used on terminal servers and user switching - if service run GUI program, it will be shown on the screen of the service. (Windows 7 notify about it and offer switch to screen of the service.)

You can solve it, if OpenSSH server will not run as windows service.

Comment: THIS PROJECT IS DISCONTINUED.

If you read the comments on the site, this software can destroys PATH variable. 

https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshwindows/