# Logging from linux to windows machine

Tags: linux

How to connect windows server via Linux command prompt?
I already tried SSH and TELNET command for connecting Windows from Linux.
It throws an error.

Comment: Take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34933/can-i-connect-to-windows-machine-from-linux-shell

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/646617/241659

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I remote login to Microsoft's Windows with the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1509180/can-i-remote-login-to-microsofts-windows-with-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

The natural (Windows POV) way would be to connect with an RDP client.
In the Linux world the standard RDP client would be 'rdesktop' your Distribution might have it included already.
If you want to connect on a CLI level you have to install a server... preferably a SSH server on the Windows system first.

For more on SSH servers for Windows see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292/what-are-some-good-ssh-servers-for-windows
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/set-up-a-free-ssh-server-on-windows-7-with-freesshd/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [winexe](https://lbtwiki.cern.ch/bin/view/Online/WinExe), see the tutorial [here](http://kokizzu.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-remotely-run-command-on-windows.html)